# Unable to change Roman numerals in footer from upper case to lower case in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a footer that was originally formatting page numbers as i, ii, iii, etc. but now only shows I, II, III, and so on. When I open the "Format Page Numbers" window, it shows that the lower case roman numerals were selected but it still only displays the upper case version. I tried switching the document to different computers, switching the formatted page numbers, and even completely removing and reformatting the numbers.

Comment: Do you have any special formatting on it, eg all caps in font?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Where could I check to make sure this is off?

Comment: It's fixed! I went into the font settings and removed the All Caps setting. Duh. lol Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Expand the Font section by clicking on the little arrow in the bottom right corner. (Home tab of the ribbon).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Double Click on the page number to edit it.

Step 2. Select the Page number.

Step 3. Right Click on it and then click on font option.

Step 4. Uncheck the box of All caps.

Step 5. All Done.